# OnClick event on canvas.drawCircle Android

Tags: android, google-maps, canvas, bitmap, onclick

I want to display few circles in google maps on my android application.

I want that when user clicks these circle it should show a toast based on the circle clicked.

I am using `code.google.android.maps.overlay` to display circle on a specific lat/long.

I am unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the ItemizedOverlay class

```
public class MapItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Drawable myPic;
    private Activity mapActivity;

    public MapItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Activity context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    this.mapActivity = context;
    this.myPic = defaultMarker;
}

    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mOberlays.get(index);
        ... //Toast code
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }
}
```

this is a class which handles overlayitems.
There you can implement the onTap()-Method and show Toasts.

In your MapActivity you simply create this MapitemizedOverlay and add your items.

```
MapItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(circleDrawable, this);
```